# i want to get the list of already set uilocalnotifications which are due today in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I have set localnotications to fire 3 times everyday using UILocalnotification class in iPhone. notications are getting triggered correctly. I want to show the list of notications which will fire today. I am saving timings of all notications in text format  into my database. How can I resolve it?

Comment: i come to know how to find the list of scheduled notifications using [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications] but from this i want to get array of firedate using localnotification object. how can i do this?